# How to prevent the user from entering the character "`" in the Input field?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input class="name-input" type="text"/>
```

I assume that there is some kind of regular expression to solve this problem, but I could not find on the Internet which one..
I will be very grateful if you help =')

Updated: the main question is how to prevent the user from entering the character "`" in the Input field. I don't understand hot to do this.

Comment: couldn't understand from the title which character you mean, is it ` or ~ or both?

Comment: 1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern#examples 2. https://www.google.com/search?q=regular+expression+exclude+character

Comment: @niceman , both. They're just on the same key, so I put "~" in parentheses.

Comment: They may be on the same key but still different characters(besides you click Shift+` to get the ~ so not exactly the same key)

Comment: What's the reason you want to prevent that character to be entered? That sounds like a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...

Comment: @Denis Not the same key on my keyboard. There's lots of different keyboard layouts with different key combinations.

Comment: @Andreas , I'm trying to prevent the user from entering the character "`" in the Input field, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Repeating the title doesn't answer my question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an eventlistener to the input field and check for any charachter, that you don't want for each keystroke.

I made a quick demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-leaf-h2syxv?file=/index.html:115-160

```js
let item = document.querySelector(".name-input");
item.addEventListener("keypress", (e) => {
  if (e.key === "~" || e.key === "`") {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<input class="name-input" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

So you should start by making a list of the special characters that you would to prevent users from using them, i assume that your list contains : [~,',",(,),`].
Then you can use this  :

```
let name = document.querySelector('.name-input')
let regex = "[`'"()~]" 
if ( name.match(regex) ){
    console.log('There was a match');
} else {
    console.log('NO match');
}
```